# How can I create a QGIS plugin that needs an external Python library?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, python-2.7, dxf

I’m trying to enhance QGIS's [Profiletool](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/profiletool/) plugin by adding DXF export functionnality. For this, I need to to import `dxfwrite` library.
As it's installed on my computer, i added the following lines to plugin code:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages")
```

With those short lines of code, I'm able to load `dxfwrite`. But it's hardcoded, so if the user does not have Python 2.7 but 3.4 (for example), library loading will probably fail because plugin will try to load `dxfwrite` from a non-existing repository. The same problem may happen if python path is not `C:\Python27\...`.

I tried to put dxfwrite sources into plugin directory, but 1) with no results, 2) if results, it would link plugin to a specific version of `dxfwrite` and 3) if results, it would increase a lot plugin size.

So, how can I properly load `dxfwrite` without facing those problems ?

Comment: Welcome to GIS.SE. This sounds more like a pure Python problem, which would be better asked over at StackOverflow.  I would suggest searching there first, because I had a similar issue a few weeks ago, and found the answer on there.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to copy your python module in the plugin dir.
and then you will get the path to your plugin with a small python script

```
import os
dirname, filename = os.path.split(os.path.abspath(__file__))
print "running from", dirname
print "file is", filename
```

This works with a C library, should be the same with a python module

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution. It uses a trick I recently had to learn, which I posted to [System variable PATH overwritten in Qgis](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/107204/system-variable-path-overwritten-in-qgis/156510#156510)

It just finds the python that's installed on your computer. I would presume python.exe is in the system path, otherwise I don't know how you would expect to find it on someone else's machine. Anyway, here's the code. I hope it helps.

```
def which(program):
    import os
    def is_exe(fpath):
        return os.path.isfile(fpath) and os.access(fpath, os.X_OK)
    fpath, fname = os.path.split(program)
    if fpath:
        if is_exe(program):
            return program
    else:
        #for path in os.environ["PATH"].split(os.pathsep):
        for path in getenv_system("PATH").split(os.pathsep):
            path = path.strip('"')
            exe_file = os.path.join(path, program)
            if is_exe(exe_file):
                return exe_file
    return None

def getenv_system(varname, default=''):
    import win32api
    import win32con
    v = default
    try:
        rkey = win32api.RegOpenKey(win32con.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, 'SYSTEM\\CurrentControlSet\\Control\\Session Manager\\Environment')
        try:
            v = str(win32api.RegQueryValueEx(rkey, varname)[0])
            v = win32api.ExpandEnvironmentStrings(v)
        except:
            pass
    finally:
        win32api.RegCloseKey(rkey)
    return v

import os
import sys
pythonexe = which('python.exe')
python_path, _ = os.path.split(pythonexe) 
lib_path = os.path.join(python_path,'Lib','site-packages')
sys.path.append(lib_path)
```

From my QGIS python console:

```
>>>lib_path
'C:\\Python34\\Lib\\site-packages'
```