# Call external programmes from python plugin in QGIS on windows

Tags: pyqgis, subprocess

I need to call an external programme from python plugin in qgis, I didn't use os.systeme because I want to hide the launched programme with 'startupinfo.dwFlags |= subprocess._subprocess.STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW'.

```
import subprocess
import os
startupinfo = None
if os.name == 'nt':
    startupinfo = subprocess.STARTUPINFO()
    startupinfo.dwFlags |= subprocess._subprocess.STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW
subprocess.Popen("TeighaFileConverter",shell=True, stdin=None, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE,startupinfo=startupinfo)
```

it's workin on pyzo but not working in QGIS editor. 
this code is working on linux but not on windows :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could also try `subprocess.call`

```
subprocess.call(["TeighaFileConverter"])
```

and make sure that you have the path to your TeighaFileConverter installation in you `path` variable

EDIT:

I tested the code above again in the python console in qgis and it didn't work, sorry for posting a wrong code, you have to mention the whole path in order to call it

```
subprocess.call(['C:/Program Files (x86)/ODA/Teigha File Converter 4.3.2/TeighaFileConverter.exe'])
```

Comment: thanks for ur comment, subprocess.call(["TeighaFileConverter"]) it's not working i've changed it to subprocess.call(["TeighaFileConverter"],shell=True) in output i get '1'

Comment: @AnassAyar Did you also add Teigha to your path variable ?

Comment: yes and I've tested running the code in pyzo and it's working

Comment: @AnassAyar I've edited my answer with a working code

Comment: now it's working thanks ! is it possible to avoid the full path to the programme ?

Comment: @AnassAyar check this https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/107204/system-variable-path-overwritten-in-qgis to use it without full path you have to overwrite path variable inside your code :/